# Jgroups Simple Chat application peer to peer communication in external networks or two different subnets

Tags: java, jgroups

I am using jgroups demo Simple chat application, its working fine in same networks as i am using this command using UDP.xml:
java -Djgroups.bind_addr=MY_IP -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true SimpleChat

but, how to use for external networks with different subnets. Try with this command using tcp.xml:-
java -Djgroups.bind_addr=MY_IP -Djgroups.external_addr=MY_PUBLIC_IP -Djgroups.tcpping.initial_hosts=MY_IP[7800],SECOND_MACHINE_IP[7800] -Djgroups.external_port=7800 -Djgroups.bind_port=7800 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true SimpleChat

I am using same command in the second machine also.But not able to connect. Firewall also closed in both the machines.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use TCP Gossip router to communicate with the external networks.